# How do I read a word from a line from a file with multiple lines?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a file, read the lines in a file, then read the words from each line. I know I need to use getline() as well as istringstream but I am getting confused on the parameters.

this is what I havem but I'm not sure if it's correct

```
getline(file, line);
            istringstream ss(word);

            ss >> word;
            totalWords++;
```

Comment: @kiner_shah if you could give me an example code of how to read words from a line from a file I could follow that as a reference and compare it to my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read a line by line into a variable using `std::getline` in a loop.

After you have read one line, you define a `std::istringstream` and put the content of the just read line into it.

Then you can extract word by word from this `std::istringstream` in a simple loop and count each occurrence of a word.

Since you want to see an example, please check the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Open  a stream for accessing data in the file
    std::ifstream sourceFileStream("test.txt");

    // Check, if the file could be opened
    if (sourceFileStream) {

        // Here we will count the total number of word
        unsigned int totalWords = 0;

        // Now read each line of the file
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(sourceFileStream, line)) {

            // Put the line into a std::istringstream, so that we can extract words
            std::istringstream iss(line);

            // And now extract all words from this istringstream (line)
            std::string word;
            while (iss >> word)
                ++totalWords;  // and, count
        }
        std::cout << "\n\nThe toal number of words in the source file is: " << totalWords << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Source file could not be opened\n\n";
}
```